# Java 8 Parse ISO-8601 date ignoring presence (or absence) of timezone

Tags: datetime, java-8, java-time, iso8601, datetime-parsing

My application should be able to parse date ignoring timezone (I always know for sure that it is UTC). The problem is that the date might come in both following forms -

`2017-09-11T12:44:07.793Z`

`0001-01-01T00:00:00`

I can parse the first one using `LocalDateTime`, and the second one using `Instant` class. Is there a way to do that using a single mechanism?

P.S. I'm trying to avoid hardcoding `Z` at the end of the input string

Comment: What should be the result? Always a `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: The goal is to get an Instant

Comment: @silent-box, you can't get an `Instant` from `0001-01-01T00:00:00` without hardcoding time zone inside the parser.

Comment: no-no, I meant I don't want to concat additional `Z` in the end of the input string. It's ok to hardcode UTC in the code. Your answer is correct and looks like it work for me with small additions

Comment: @silent-box Exactly how is "hard-coding UTC in the code" really different from "concat additional Z"? They both have the very same effect. Except that concatenating the `Z` makes your  intentions quite clear in very little code: Correcting faulty input data.

Comment: @BasilBourque Concatenating a "Z" to every string that's parsed can easily lead to faulty code and is considered bad practice, not to mention that it would be unnecessary and wasteful for a large number of strings. It is much better to establish intentions through the object being used and to well-document clarifying explanations of the purpose of the code and its behavior. Consider the selected answer and its code snippet, which does this and includes short, but well-clarifying comments easing understanding even for those mostly unfamiliar with the API.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the `Z` offset is optional, you can use a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` with an optional section:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date/time
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    // optional offset
    .optionalStart().appendOffsetId()
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
```

Then you can use the `parseBest` method, with a list of `TemporalQuery`'s that tries to create the correspondent object. Then you check the return type and act accordingly:

```
Instant instant = null;
// tries to create Instant, and if it fails, try a LocalDateTime
TemporalAccessor parsed = fmt.parseBest("2017-09-11T12:44:07.793Z", Instant::from, LocalDateTime::from);
if (parsed instanceof Instant) {
    instant = (Instant) parsed;
} else if (parsed instanceof LocalDateTime) {
    // convert LocalDateTime to UTC instant
    instant = ((LocalDateTime) parsed).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
}
System.out.println(instant); // 2017-09-11T12:44:07.793Z
```

Running with the second input (`0001-01-01T00:00:00`) produces the `Instant` equivalent to `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

In the example above, I used just `Instant::from` and `LocalDateTime::from`, so the formatter tries to first create an `Instant`. If it's not possible, then it tries to create a `LocalDateTime`. You can add as many types you want to that list (for example, I could add `ZonedDateTime::from`, and if a `ZonedDateTime` is created, I could just convert to `Instant` using `toInstant()` method).

---

As you know for sure that the input is always in UTC, you can also set it directly in the formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date/time
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    // optional offset
    .optionalStart().appendOffsetId()
    // create formatter with UTC
    .toFormatter().withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

So you can parse it directly to `Instant`:

```
System.out.println(Instant.from(fmt.parse("2017-09-11T12:44:07.793Z"))); // 2017-09-11T12:44:07.793Z
System.out.println(Instant.from(fmt.parse("0001-01-01T00:00:00"))); // 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! I really like the builder, will use.

Comment: @silent-box, note that it's not imperative to use existing method references when calling `parseBest`: you can write your own methods that will produce desired types of `Temporal` objects. I have an example in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can "parseBest", like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[Z]");

Temporal parsed = parser.parseBest(inputString, Instant::from, LocalDateTime::from);
```

Then you should check what did get parsed, and act accordingly.
The `parseBest` method will work with any type of `TemporalQuery`, including most of `from` methods available on `java.time` classes. So you can lengthen that list with `LocalDate.from`, for example.

You can also use that method and lambdas to coerse parse results to the type you want without having `instanceof` checks that are external for result resolution (although not without one cast):

```
Instant parsed = (Instant) parser.parseBest(inputString,
                    Instant::from,
                    interResult -> LocalDateTime.from(interResult).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant())
```

Notice that second option uses lambda that converts `LocalDateTime` to `ZonedDateTime` and then to `Instant`, so the parse results are always coersed to `Instant`.

Comment: *trying to avoid hardcoding Z at the end of the string* in the question

Comment: @nullpointer, I don't even know what that'd look like. Is there also a goal of not hardcoding `yyyy` in the pattern or something equally strange?

Comment: Although I suppose there are optional pattern parts. But `Z` will still be in the string, so guess it's not possible?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I meant don't want hardcode `Z` into the input string. It's ok to have `Z` in the pattern :)

Comment: Here's what works for me in both cases: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSSX]").parseBest("2017-09-11T12:44:07.793Z", Instant::from, LocalDateTime::from);`

Comment: @silent-box, cool. Hugo's answer looks more fleshed out, so if what he suggested worked, please mark his answer as accepted.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, just did that. Thanks again. @Hugo, it works indeed: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSSX]").parseBest("0001-01-01T00:00:00", Instant::from, LocalDateTime::from);`

Comment: @Hugo, ah, so it does always need optional parts if one wants to `parseBest`. Noted. I'll update.

Comment: @silent-box I was talking about `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` pattern, it doesn't work for `0001-01-01T00:00:00`. Also, `parseBest` returns a `TemporalAccessor` (so the code in the answer requires a cast to `Temporal` as well).

Comment: @silent-box Another detail is that when using `[.SSSX]`, **both** fraction of seconds and offset will be optional (so either you have both, or none). Using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` (as in my answer), the fraction of seconds can be optional regardless of the offset (so just one of them can be in the input, or both, or none). A little detail, but you must check which one fits best to your inputs.

Comment: @silent-box, Hugo is correct, if you want fracion seconds to be optional, and you want your pattern as string, then it's better to have `[.SSS][X]` at the very least, so there's two independent optional sections in pattern.

Comment: I get it, now it's all clear. Thank you once again guys!